# undefined value from subscribe to observable

Tags: angular

I know there is number of questions regarding this problem, but non of them helps to solve my problem.
Subscribing to the service from component, it is always return undefined.. loosing my mind over this.

**component**:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.dataService.getAllPartners().subscribe(data => 
      {this.partners = data
        console.log("data " + data);},// i can see the data returns 
      error => {
      LoggerService.error('Failed to load partners.')
    });
    console.log("Partners " + this.partners);// partners is undefined 
  }
```

[image]

**service:**

```
 private serviceUrl = '/partners';
 private headers = new HttpHeaders()
    .set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

    /**
   * Fetch  partners from the server
   */   
    getAllPartners(searchParams?: Object): Observable<Partner[]> {
      return  this.httpClient.get(Constants.BASE_SERVICE_URL + serviceUrl , {
        params: HttpRequestService.buildRequestOptions(searchParams),
        headers: this.headers
    })

}
```

Comment: *"non of them helps to solve my problem"* - on the contrary, many of the existing questions tell you exactly what the problem is: *outside* the subscription, the callback hasn't yet been invoked and therefore the property *cannot* be set. You can see this in your console: the `Partners` are printed **before** the `data`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically this line of code

```
console.log("Partners " + this.partners);
```

is running before the code inside the `.subscribe`

```
   this.dataService.getAllPartners().subscribe(data => { 
    // What happens here is after the request has been processed
}
```

Thats because the subscribe is an asynchronous operation and takes some time, so you need to do your console.log inside the subscribe.

Be aware that subscriptions are long living and need to be unsubscribed with your component like this below.

```
import {  Subscription } from 'rxjs';

    private subscription : Subscription;
    ngOnInit() {
       this.subscription = this.dataService.getAllPartners().subscribe(data =>
            {this.partners = data;
                console.log("data " + data);}, 
            error => {
                LoggerService.error('Failed to load partners.')
            });

    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
```

But you also should not be subscribing the way you are. Ideally you should subscribe using the `| async` pipe inside your template as angular will then handle all of that for you.

So in your component do this

```
ngOnInit() {
           this.partners = this.dataService.getAllPartners();
        }
```

and in your template

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let partner of partners | async">
    // Your html markup for each partner here 
    {{partner.name}}
 </ng-container>
```

Comment: I new to angular.. you are my hero! The only problem is | async  on the template was giving me "InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object],[object Object]" error. So i had to remove it

Comment: No problem :), I would need to see your html markup to see what is wrong with the pipe. The async pipe is part of angular so no need to import anything. Which version of angular are you using btw ?

Comment: i am using angular 7.1.3...  my trace is to long for the comment , but my application works fine now :) i can finally move forward. Thanks again!

Comment: Ah ok .. you are probably still subscribing to the observable in your component so you don't need the async pipe then. (make sure you unsubscribe in ```ngOnDestroy()```)