# expression watched in Chrome Dev Tools not showing value

Tags: angular, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

I'm working on an Angular's app.

I have this question. I'm putting a `debugger;` because I want to see what is returning the property `this.facturas` in the `watch` section in `source` tab. But, After running the app, and having it stopped where I want, when looking at the `watch` I just get `undefined` for `this.facturas`, but the thing is that it actually has a value:  It's an array of objects that is populating the row's `td's` in a table in my .html template.

the .ts code:

```
 this.documentosService.getFacturas(this.requestCuatro).subscribe((data: any) => {
      if (data) {
        if (data.documentos.length == 0 && data.error.codError == 0) {
          swal("Stop! Trolls and Dragons found!");
        } else {
          this.facturas = data.documentos;
          debugger;       
        }

        if (data.error.codError != 0) {
          swal("Warning! Sorry, the old Monarc Elf died :(");
        }
      }
    });
```

I want to be able to see what values I'm getting back from server, but I'm not sure how. I'm watching `this.facturas`, but I get undefined, so I'm coding a bit as if my eyes were covered.

Any help? Thanks.

Comment: I had the same question when I just started. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54026858/undefined-value-from-subscribe-to-observable

Answer (score 1):

Try watching `_this.facturas` or `this_.facturas`. Angular is transpiled javascript from typescript, and because you are inside an arrow function, the `this` property from the class will be stored in another variable (this_ or _this, cannot remember now) to maintain the `this` context in your code.

I personally don't use the 'watch' inside the debugger, but usually just look in the 'scope' section. In there I never have the issue though that `this` is not referencing the right context. Perhaps you are compiling without sourcemaps enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Two more more reliable ways to see the API responses:

1. Log the response - this outputs the value directly to the Console tab.

   ```
   } else {
     this.facturas = data.documentos;
     console.log(this.facturas);       
   }
   ```
2. Watch the Network tab instead: the network/API requests can be directly observed under the Network tab. Find the request that's going out, and check the response body: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network/reference#response

Comment: My dear friend. console.log() is not working for me anymore. I've searched the whole web trying to find an answer and tried plenty of posted solutions, however, I can not get the values printed in console with my old friend console.log()  :(